# HTML5 background video not playing

Tags: javascript, css, html, video

I'm using a video off cover -  it's just a html video I'm playing to the full width. The problem is it is not playing the mp4, instead it is using the default image. I have the mp4 and webm in the same directory as the index. Here is my html:

```
<div class="homepage-hero-module">
    <div class="video-container">
        <div class="filter"></div>
        <video autoplay loop class="fillWidth">
            <source src="Browsing.mp4" type="video/mp4" />Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
            <source src="Browsing.webm" type="video/webm" />Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
        </video>
        <div class="poster hidden">
            <img src="Browsing.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my css :

```
.homepage-hero-module {
    border-right: none;
    border-left: none;
    position: relative;
}
.no-video .video-container video,
.touch .video-container video {
    display: none;
}
.no-video .video-container .poster,
.touch .video-container .poster {
    display: block !important;
}
.video-container {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #000;
}
.video-container .poster img {
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
.video-container .filter {
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    width: 100%;
}
.video-container video {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.video-container video.fillWidth {
    width: 100%;
}
```

And finally, my JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    scaleVideoContainer();

    initBannerVideoSize('.video-container .poster img');
    initBannerVideoSize('.video-container .filter');
    initBannerVideoSize('.video-container video');

    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        scaleVideoContainer();
        scaleBannerVideoSize('.video-container .poster img');
        scaleBannerVideoSize('.video-container .filter');
        scaleBannerVideoSize('.video-container video');
    });

});

function scaleVideoContainer() {

    var height = $(window).height() + 5;
    var unitHeight = parseInt(height) + 'px';
    $('.homepage-hero-module').css('height',unitHeight);

}

function initBannerVideoSize(element){

    $(element).each(function(){
        $(this).data('height', $(this).height());
        $(this).data('width', $(this).width());
    });

    scaleBannerVideoSize(element);

}

function scaleBannerVideoSize(element){

    var windowWidth = $(window).width(),
    windowHeight = $(window).height() + 5,
    videoWidth,
    videoHeight;

    console.log(windowHeight);

    $(element).each(function(){
        var videoAspectRatio = $(this).data('height')/$(this).data('width');

        $(this).width(windowWidth);

        if(windowWidth < 1000){
            videoHeight = windowHeight;
            videoWidth = videoHeight / videoAspectRatio;
            $(this).css({'margin-top' : 0, 'margin-left' : -(videoWidth - windowWidth) / 2 + 'px'});

            $(this).width(videoWidth).height(videoHeight);
        }

        $('.homepage-hero-module .video-container video').addClass('fadeIn animated');

    });
}
```

I basically just followed the instructions coverr gave whenI downloaded the video file. Can anyone see why the video wouldn't be playing?

Comment: Any errors? Is the jQuery script included on your page?

Comment: Try if it plays in a normal video element, with all the CSS and JS removed, first.

Comment: do you have **Browsing.mp4** on your local folder ? Did you add a call to the jquery librairy ?

Comment: Yeah it plays without all the css and html, browsing.mp4 is there and jquery is there.Also no errors.

Comment: Because i tried your script, and it is definitely working

Comment: check this out : https://jsbin.com/bafavuvenu/edit?html,output

Comment: I see it works on codepen but again for me its just defaulting to Browsing.jpg again :/

Answer (score 1):

I created a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/brettdewoody/pen/dOwXXp) of your code and it works, but your image covers the video. I think you meant to place the image in the `<video>` element as a fallback.

```
<video autoplay loop class="fillWidth">
  <source src="Browsing.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="Browsing.webm" type="video/webm" />
  <img src="Browsing.jpg" alt="">
</video>
```

Comment: Thanks for that mate, but even when i use your code i just see the bunny jpg, if i inspect it's just refering to the jpeg and not the mp4

Comment: It takes a minute but the video starts playing. The Codepen uses the same setup you describe so the video is still behind the image. You need to use the code I've shown above.